# Unable to find IPv6 address for ORPort 4xxxx. You might want to specify IPv4Only to it or set an explicit address or set Address

Tags: bridge, network-configuration

As I have very limited ISP options, the one I chose is not IPv6-capable.

In `nyx` this message popped up onto me:

```
Unable to find IPv6 address for ORPort 4xxxx. You might want to specify IPv4Only to it or set an explicit address or set Address.
```

I find it curious, that almost no where is this `IPv4Only` option documented or at the very least said where to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using search I found this:

https://forum.torproject.org/t/how-do-i-configure-ipv4only-options-in-torrc-files/1273

which states:

> `ORPort` < number > **`IPv4Only`**

which I am testing right now,

Further there is hint here:

https://forum.torproject.org/t/need-to-disable-publishing-ipv6-addresses-in-relay-descriptor/1409

which states another line, not sure I need it, `nyx` is *happy* it appears now:

```
AddressDisableIPv6 1
```